# Laravel 8 api how to send token via Authorization

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-8

I am using Laravel 8 as a APIrest and I am trying to send my token in the ajax petition but in laravel I get null, I cannot see why. I do not have problems with log in or petitions without token.

In JavaScript I have an AJAX petition like this: (Before sending token is not null, I save it in localStorage)

```
var settings = {
  "url": apiUrl+"bookings/"+userIdentified.id,
  "method": "GET",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization": token
  },
};
        
$.ajax(settings).done((response) => {
   console.log(response);
});
```

In Laravel, I have a middleware with the following:

```
// Check user identified
$token = $request->header('Authorization');
$jwtAuth = new \JwtAuth();
$checkToken = $jwtAuth->checkToken($token);

// If it is continue
if ($checkToken) return $next($request);

// If it is not then return an error
$data = array(
  'status'    => 'error',
  'code'      => '400',
  'message'   => $token, // I tested that and it return null
  'test' => $request->all()
);

return response()->json($data, $data['code']);
```

The route:

```
Route::get('/bookings/{id}', [BookingController::class, 'getBookingsByUser'])->middleware('auth');
```

And this is the response:

```
{
  code: "400",
  status: "error",
  message: null, // that have to be the token for testing that exists and is not null
  test: []
}
```

In web console:

```
GET https://my-url/api/bookings/4 400 (Bad Request)
```

- In laravel, I commented VerifyCsrfToken in kernel.php to not have problems with it.
- I have the api in a subdomain but I do not have problem doing register and log in, that works without token. For some reason the token is not arriving to my api :(

There is something that I am missing?

Comment: Check your chrome dev tools Network tab to see if you are sending the token in the headers, maybe there is something wrong in your JS code and is not adding the token to it, check that in the network tab. Also, small tip, on your Middleware, do not do `if ($checkToken) return $next($request);`, that guard clause is wrong, do the inverse, if it is not okay return the error, if you continue without error, do `return $next($request);`. See [this example](https://codeinphp.github.io/post/replace-nested-conditions-with-guard-clauses/).

Comment: What is the token type?

Comment: The token type is `bearer`. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#issuing-api-tokens AND https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `bearer` which specifies the token type.

Change:

```
"Authorization": token
```

To:

```
"Authorization": "bearer token"
```

Also, if you are making an API request add this header:

```
"accept": "application/json"
```

Comment: It was that, really thanks! One thing, now in php I have this token = "Bearer \"token\"", I need just the token o even token with "" is okay but I can't split that backslash. Do you know how to? I tried with explode, stripslashes and str_replace('\\', '', $token) but nothing

Comment: @Toni - create a new question. I am not certain what you are asking. Note, when you see `\"`, the quote is escaped.